# youtube video not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

After clicking the thumbnail, the youtube video is not opening. It leaves white blank, have to reload to see the main video

```css
$(function () {
  var videos=$(".video");
  videos.on("click", function () {
    var elm=$(this), conts=elm.contents(), le=conts.length, ifr=null;
    for (var i=0;
    i < le;
    i++) {
      if (conts[i].nodeType==8) ifr=conts[i].textContent;
    }
    elm.addClass("player").html(ifr);
    elm.off("click");
  }
  );
}

)
```

```html
<div class="video">
  <img class="zoom-video" src="~/image/body/special-offer.png">
  <iframe width="600" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ze7xsy9tVVQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Check the console of the browser (*press F12 key ->**Console** tab*) and check the error(s) you might get and please post them in your question - press [edit]. Also (*while testing your code*), I got this message: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'PresentationRequest': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-presentation' flag.` Same with and `allow-same-origin`. Probably the erro you have is due to these reasons. Please double-check and add the error description (*if any*) in your question.

Comment: There's no error popping up :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy the provided iframe from the video. Go to the video, click share, then click embed. 
Copy paste the code there and try to run the code again. 
Here's an example:

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Still not working